# Scientific Source that states, that a one way hash function is not encryption

Tags: cryptography

I am currently writing my master-thesis and I want to state in a subsection, that a one way hash function is not a method of encryption. But because it is a thesis, I must supply a scientific source for such a statement. My first guess was "Applied Cryptography" from Bruce Schneier, but he never explicitly says, that a one way hash function is not a method of encryption.

Can anyone give my a hint where I should look for a solid quote? Internet articles are not allowed in this thesis, a book or scientific paper would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hope this helps! :)

CCSP CSPFA Exam Cram 2 (Exam Cram 642-521) By Daniel P. Newman (page 273)

> "Hashing is not encryption, but
>   actually a result from an algorithm."

Oracle PL/SQL Programming By Steven Feuerstein, Bill Pribyl (page 939)

> "Hashing is not encryption because you
>   can't decipher the original value from
>   the hash value."

MSDN magazine, Volume 18, Issues 7-12 (page 55)

> "Technically, hashing is not
>   encryption ..."

Black Hat physical device security: exploiting hardware and software By Drew Miller (page 122)

> "Hashing is not encryption"

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! Exactly what I needed. A shame I do not have enough reputation yet to vote this up.

Comment: Seriously, you don't need a source for this statement!  It's like saying a real number has no imaginary part.  It's obvious, and the one-sentence explanation should be enough.  If I was reading a thesis where this was *cited* from somewhere I would smile and think "that's odd".

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a source because hashing is by definition not reversible, therefore it is by definition not encryption.  As a source for that statement goes, any book which covers hashing or cryptography would do (like the one you suggest).